# Add custom cart field to woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, cart, custom-fields

This may be a noob question, but I've googled a lot and haven't found the answer. I've already replaced the woocommerce cart to my child theme subfolder.

I'm trying to add a field to the woocommerce cart, so it will just display the cart subtotal multiplied by a number defined by me. I.e., the cart subtotal is 3,000.00, I want to define the multiplier number 3, so the field I want to show must display 9.000,00.

I've already added the field header to the cart:

```
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="product-quantity"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'thefoxwp' ); ?></th>
        <th class="product-subtotal"><?php _e( 'Total', 'thefoxwp' ); ?></th>
        <th class="product-result"><?php _e( 'Total to be Received', 'thefoxwp' ); ?></th>

    </tr>
</thead>
```

The field I want to configure is the `class="product-result"`.

It's not a input field, it will just show the subtotal multiplied by a number defined by me.

I need this information to be sent with the woocommerce email to the client and saved in my order details.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/, although it takes caer of adding fields on product, cart, checkout, order and email too. but you will be needing some customization on your cart page template.

Comment: I downloaded it, but it just allow to add fields to the product page. I can create a hidden field that will show on the cart and checkout page, but how can I make the result of this field be the multiplication of the subtotal and the numbe I decide?

Answer (score 0):

Could figure it out.

I added two classes to the header

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="product-quantity"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'thefoxwp' ); ?></th>
        <th class="product-subtotal"><?php _e( 'Total', 'thefoxwp' ); ?></th>
        <th class="product-tax"><?php _e( 'Exchange Tax', 'thefoxwp' ); ?></th>
        <th class="product-result"><?php _e( 'Total to be Received', 'thefoxwp' ); ?></th>

    </tr>
</thead>
```

And then added this code

```
       <!-- Exchange Tax -->
       <td class="product-tax">
       <?php
       $tax = 4.05;
       echo "R$ $tax";
       ?>
       </td>

      <!-- Product Result -->
      <td class="product-result">
        <?php
        $resultado = WC()->cart->subtotal;
        $mostrar = $resultado * $tax;
        echo "R$ "; echo number_format("$mostrar",2);
        ?>
      </td>
```

So it's now `echo` the result of the cart subtotal * the exchange tax.

But now, how can I get this variable to `echo` on the email sent by woocommerce and on the checkout page?